# PHP - Right way to generate array objects (manual)

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am generating new multidimensional object array from object array outed from DB.

Is using "(object)" before "array" correct way? Or is this tottaly bad solution.

```
$new_results = array();

foreach($result as $assoc_agent)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($assoc_agent->agent_id, $new_results))
    {
        $new_results[$assoc_agent->agent_id] = (object)array(
            'agent_id'      => $assoc_agent->agent_id,
            'agent_name'    => $assoc_agent->agent_name
        );
    }   

    $new_results[$assoc_agent->agent_id]->subordinate_users[] = $assoc_agent->user_id;
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [agent_id] => 1
        [agent_name] => Joan Visielsky
        [subordinate_users] => Array
            (
                [0] => 100000
                [1] => 100011
            )

    )
    ....
)
```

Comment: you are using right way ...

Answer (score 0):

## [Type Casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) :

> The meaning of type casting is to use the value of a variable with
>   different data type. In other word typecasting is a way to utilize one
>   data type variable into the different data type.

```
$object = (object)$array;
```

Or You may use

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);
```